# SQL Conditional Query dropping Null Entries

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I have a huge survey data in the excel file that I want to Bulk insert into DB, however I want cleaned data to be inserted.

Lets say I have following entries

[image: Table]

First three Columns named "ID,Year,Company" are NOT NULLs, whereas rest of the columns can be NULL.

I want to write a contitional sql query for insertion into SQL Database so that only fields with Non-empty records are inserted, i.e in my case all the records for "diamler" should be inserted whereas for tesla they shouldnt be inserted into DB because all the fields are empty. If one of the rows for tesla were non-empty(excluding NOT NULLS), then insertion should have been done for all the records, keeping empty entries as NULL place holder.

Comment: Load the data into a staging table and do the logic in SQL.  The data is coming from Excel so it is not really that big.

Comment: Excel doesn't support half a million columns, did you swap your numbers? Otherwise Gordon Linoff suggestion is the way to go; in SQL you can use statements kinda `delete from xxx where not exists(...)` or `isnull(...)` - million rows is not a problem in there. BTW, why `triggers` tag?

Comment: @hsn It [seems](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) that Excel supports a maximum of 16,384 columns. If you have three files with about 500,000 columns does that mean that each file has many sheets? Can the data for a `Year`/`Company` pair be spread across sheets and files? If so, it complicates checking for non-empty rows if the data isn't imported to a single staging table.

Comment: And the other question: Can `1928`/`'DeSoto'` turn up in more than one file? If all of the rows are empty in two out of three files, but the third has something fun, then the data from all three files needs to be inserted.

Comment: @HABO Every file has unique combination of ID Year and Company, it can't be repeated so lets say we only have the above mentioned example file. The reason why I mentioned about 3 files and huge data is because someone wont recommend that simply write INSERT where (address, country, state... NOT NULL)